# How to write a zip file from a request body to a file on Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, zip, writetofile

I am trying to write a node server that can receive a zip file of PDFs and JSON. In order to utilize it on the server I need to write it to a file on the server where I can call other functions on the internal data.

However with my current method, I can successfully write to a file in the server but when trying to open it in windows, I get an error "The Compressed (zipped) Folder  is invalid."

I've tried directly piping the request to fs.createWriteStream with the same result as the code below

```
    app.route('/myRoute').post(rawParser, function (req, res, next) {

    let serverFileName = `${req.connection.remoteAddress.substring(7)}_${Date.now()}.zip`
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/${serverFileName}`, 'binary');

    // console.log(req.rawBody);
    writeStream.write(req.rawBody);
    writeStream.end();
    writeStream.on('error', err => {
        logger.logger(err);

        res.status = 500;
        res.send("Server did not accept File");
    });
    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        logger.logger(`Writing to file: ${serverFileName}`);
        res.status = 201;
        res.send("Successfully Wrote file to server");
    });
});
```

Here is my rawParser middleware

```
const rawParser = function (req, res, next) {
    req.rawBody = [];
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        req.rawBody.push(chunk);
        console.log(chunk)
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        req.rawBody = Buffer.concat(req.rawBody);
        next();
    });
}
```

I'm fairly new to node and javascript coding. I am welcome to any tips including your solutions